# Limit date selection from 1994-2000

Tags: java, android

I have the above code and I want to add the date limit in that code! But I still haven't figured out how!
I would like to limit the number of users who choose a birth date from 1996-2000 in android.

Comment: One option would be a before insert trigger on your user table, which would check the user count for that birthday range, should the user's admitted birthday be between 1996 and 2000.

Comment: protected Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    
    protected DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Date date = new GregorianCalendar(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth).getTime();
            onBirthDateSelect(date);
        }
    };

Comment: Please, try to improve your question by adding more information about context. Have you an activity or a fragment in which you have already put a DatePicker? What have you try to solve your problem?

Comment: @xcesco help me please

Comment: I want to help you, but I need more information. It's difficult to you help you with only with information that you gave.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a validation to Date input.

An article to use a validation library is [here](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-form-validation-tutorial/).

I hope this helps.